# FluentAssertions Asserting an Exception has been thrown for an overloaded operator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I've been using FluentAssertions for my unit testing, and have started looking at asserting whether Exceptions are thrown correctly. I know that I can use the `ExpectedExceptions` method attribute, but I would like to learn the FluentAssertion approach if it is possible.

I have a `Matrix` class (simplified for this example) with an overloaded multiplication operator:

```
public class Matrix
{
    public int Rows { get; set; }
    public int Columns { get; set; }
    public float[,] Elements { get; set; }

    public static Matrix operator *(Matrix m1, Matrix m2)
    {
        if (m1.Columns != m2.Rows)
        {
            throw new Exception("These matrices cant be multiplied");
        }

        return new Matrix(1, 2, new float[,] { {1, 2} });
    }
}
```

and I would like to test for the Exception case. This is what I have so far:

```
[TestMethod]
//[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception), "These matrices cant be multiplied")]
public void MatrixMultiplication_IncorrectMatrixSize_ExceptionTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var elementsA = new float[,]
    {
        {4, 7},
        {6, 8}
    };

    var elementsB = new float[,]
    {
        {3, 0},
        {1, 1},
        {5, 2}
    };

    Matrix A = new Matrix() {Rows=2, Columns=2, Elements=elementsA);
    Matrix B = new Matrix() {Rows=3, Columns=2, Elements=elementsB);

    // Act
    Func<Matrix, Matrix, Matrix> act = (mA, mB) => mA * mB;

    // Assert
    act(A,B).ShouldThrow<Exception>().WithInnerMessage("These matrices cant be multiplied");
}
```

The problem I'm having is that FluentAssertions doesn't have a `ShouldThrow` extension method for a generic `Func`, and I'm not sure if or how to wrap this in an Action. Is it possible to use FluentAssertions in this way for this situation, or do I use FluentAssertions in a different manner, or will I have to use `ExpectedExceptions`?

Comment: Don't the [docs](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#exceptions) explain this?

Comment: (e.g. as an Action: `Action<Matrix, Matrix> act = (mA, mB) => { var x = mA * mB; }`)

Comment: @DavidG I have been looking at the docs, but for me it didn't make it clear what I should be doing in this particular case. You're right, I can write an `Action` that way, and use it instead of a `Func`, but the `ShouldThrow` extension still can't be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooray for overthinking the problem...

Writing the TestMethod like this made it work:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MatrixMultiplication_IncorrectMatrixSize_ExceptionTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var elementsA = new float[,]
    {
        {4, 7},
        {6, 8}
    };

    var elementsB = new float[,]
    {
        {3, 0},
        {1, 1},
        {5, 2}
    };

    Matrix A = new Matrix() {Rows=2, Columns=2, Elements=elementsA);
    Matrix B = new Matrix() {Rows=3, Columns=2, Elements=elementsB);

    // Act
    Action act = () => { var x = A * B; };

    // Assert
    act.ShouldThrow<Exception>().WithMessage("These matrices cant be multiplied");
}
```